# about compare from sys.argv to file.txt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the problem with my code: 
all is work well but only the compare

```
for hosts in s:
    for line in fin:
        if hosts==line:
            print line
```

This dosn't work and don't output nothing on the cmd.

```
import os.path
import sys
'''////if not enouth suffix in the code////'''
if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print "Please write %s <FileLocation>  <hostname1> <hostname2> " % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

'''////check if the file is exist in the dir////'''
filelocation = sys.argv[1]
if os.path.exists(filelocation) == False:
    print "File dosnt exist please write after %s <exist file> " % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

'''////compare from the sys.argv to the file////'''
with open(filelocation,"r") as fin:
    s = set(sys.argv[2:])
    for hosts in s:
        for line in fin:
            if hosts==line:
                print line
```

Comment: Try printing 1. the value 2. the type of both `hosts` and `line`, before each `if`. It's probably a comparison problem.

Comment: i print them before the if and its work well the problem is only in the if i think

Comment: please fix you indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `line` contains the newline (`\n`) at the end of the line in the text file.

Use `str.strip()` to remove these.

```
with open(filelocation,"r") as fin:
    s = set(sys.argv[2:])
    for host in s:
        for line in fin:
            if host==line.strip():
                print line
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: you have to strip the whitespaces and newlines from the file's content. Second problem: once the first problem is corrected, you'll find out that the inner loop is only executed for the first outer loop, because after the first outer loop you've reached the end of the file so there's nothing left to iter upon.

Unless your file is really huge, the best solution would be to make it a set first, then use set operations to get the intersection:

```
s1 = set(sys.argv[2:])
with open(filelocation) as fin:
    s2 = set(filter(None, (line.strip() for line in fin))) 
print "\n".join(s1 & s2)
```

If you expect huge files then you will have to invert the loops:

```
s = set(sys.argv[2:])
with open(filelocation) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line in s:
            print line
```

This avoids exhausting the file, and is also more efficient as set lookups are O(1) (instead of O(N) with your current algorithm).

Comment: this is dsnt work ... i try to edit my code to what you write for me in the first code and in the second and both dont work

Comment: and when i write this line
s2 = set(filter(None, line.strip() for line in fin))

its show me error in the launch

its tell me this error :
Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Comment: so what did you do to fix this last issue? The error message is quite clear... As to your previous comment, "doesn't work" is the least useful report you could come with. If you hope to get more help you need to post useful informations - the exact code, the data set and the full trace back